# Vector Space Notation question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, vectors

I have a question on notation used for vectors and a vector spaces.  I'm using the [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) page for Euclidean Space and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) for vectors.  Definitions are provided and **questions** are identified in bold.

A *bound vector* or pair of points, with initial point $P$ and terminal point $Q$ is:
$$
\vec{PQ}_b = (P, Q)
$$
where $P,Q \in E$.

A *free vector* from the origin:
$$
\mathbf v = \vec v = \vec {0\mathbf v} = \vec {O\mathbf v} = a_0\hat {\mathbf b_0} + ...+ a_n\hat {\mathbf b_1}
$$
where the ordered basis is $B = (\mathbf b_0, ...,\mathbf b_n)$, $\mathbf b_n = (p_0,...,p_n) \in E$ and Euclidean Space $E = \mathbb{R}^n$.

A *free vector* is also [defined on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipollence_(geometry)) as an equivalence class of bound vectors, where $\bumpeq$ is equipollence (have the same length and direction), defined as true when a parallelogram can be drawn between $a,b,P,Q$:
$$
w = [\vec {PQ}_b]= \{(a, b) : a \in E \land b \in E \land \vec{ab}_b \bumpeq \vec{PQ}_b\}
$$
or using the difference operator:
$$
w = [\vec {PQ}_b] = \{(a, b) : a \in E \land b \in E \land ( b -  a =  Q -  P)\}
$$

It's my understanding when using the equivalence relation above, the vector addition operation is defined as another equivalence relation:
$$
\vec{E} = \{[\vec {PQ}_b] : P \in E \land Q \in E\}
$$
$$
+_v : \vec{E} \times \vec{E} \rightarrow \vec{E}
$$
$$ v = +_v(w_0, w_1) = \{(a,c) : (a,b) \in w_0 \land (b,c) \in w_1\}
$$

**Question** do the above definitions look correct?

The definitions below define $\vec{PQ}_b$ as a *free vector* and not a equivalence class of bound vectors as above.  The following definition agrees with *Hamilton - Elements of Quaternions* Page 1:
$$
\vec{PQ} = Q - P = \mathbf v
$$

which can be put into correspondence with bound vectors:

From a free vector to equivalence class:
$$
f(\vec{PQ}) = [\vec{PQ}_b]
$$

From equivalence class to a bound vector with $\vec 0$ origin:
$$
g([\vec{PQ}_b]) = \cup \{(\vec 0, y) \in [\vec{PQ}_b] : y \in E\}
$$
From a bound vector to a free vector:
$$
\vec{PQ} = f^-1([\vec{PQ}_b]) = \cup \{b - a : (a, b) = g(\vec{PQ}_b) \} 
$$

Vector space of free vectors:
$$
\vec E = \{\vec{PQ} : P \in E \land Q \in E\}
$$

$P$ is a point of $E$ then:
$$
E = \{P + \mathbf v : \mathbf v \in \vec{E}\}
$$
$$
P + \vec{E} = \{P + \mathbf v : \mathbf v \in \vec{E}\}
$$
A line:
$$
L = \{P + \lambda \vec{PQ} : \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
A line segment:
$$
PQ = QP = \{P + \lambda \vec{PQ} : 0 \le \lambda \le 1\}
$$

Finally, distance:
$$
d(P, Q) = ||\vec{PQ}||
$$

Comment: @MishaLavrov I added the correct Wiki to the beginning of the post

Comment: Okay, that clarifies things.

Comment: I suspect my confusion is if a bound vector is represented by an ordered pair of two points.  If it is so, then why is a bound vector used in later forms.  If the bound vector is equal to the distance between it's two points (and not an ordered pair) then the later forms seem to make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary mistake in the definitions I see is that there is no "vector space of bound vectors". Only the free vectors form a vector space.

You can add the bound vectors $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ and $\overrightarrow{QR}$ to get the bound vector $\overrightarrow{PR}$. However, two bound vectors **cannot** be added if the endpoint of the first is not the start of the second. In a vector space, we should be able to add any two vectors, so this doesn't satisfy those conditions.

For any bound vector $\overrightarrow{PQ}$, we have a corresponding free vector: the free vector represented by the ordered pair $Q-P$. Most people don't talk about bound vectors at all, and so for them $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ simply **is** the free vector $Q-P$. In particular:

- In the Wikipedia article on [Euclidean vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector), $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ denotes a bound vector.
- In the Wikipedia article on [Euclidean spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space), bound vectors do not appear, and $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ denotes the free vector $Q-P$.

Another way to define free vectors, instead of the ordered pair $Q-P$, is as the equivalence class of all bound vectors with the same value of $Q-P$. Since such an equivalence class goes hand in hand with the value of $Q-P$, it doesn't matter too much which we use. Some considerations:

- You might want to use the equivalence class definition if bound vectors are in the picture. The nice property it has is that the definition of $\vec v + \vec w$ for free vectors appears directly out of its definition for bound vectors: you choose any vector $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ in the equivalence class $\vec v$, choose specifically the vector $\overrightarrow{QR}$ in the equivalence class $\vec w$ that starts at $Q$, then add them together to get a representative of $\vec v + \vec w$.
- On the other hand, just defining a free vector as $Q-P$ means it's a more concrete object rather than an equivalence class, and doesn't require us to talk about bound vectors at all.

As a side note, I would not say that a bound vector is an ordered pair $(P,Q)$, but rather that there is a one-to-one correspondence between bound vectors and such ordered pairs. They contain all the same data, but are different types of things. But this is a very minor thing.

Comment: You cleared most of this up. It appears $\vec{PQ} = \mathbf Q - \mathbf P$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipollence_(geometry) says "A to B is a bound vector, while the class of segments equipollent to it is a free vector" denoted $\vec{AB} \bumpeq \vec{CD}$.  So if $\vec{PQ}$ is an equivalence class (set of equivalent bound vectors), how can $\vec{PQ} = \mathbf Q - \mathbf P$?  Any idea how to denote the equivalence class?

Comment: This site also specifies the bound vector as a equivalence class as mentioned above https://handwiki.org/wiki/Physics:Vector_(mathematics_and_physics).  Unsure how to specify that

Comment: That's yet another definition! I've added some discussion of it.

Comment: I updated the post with clarification.  I think you have me thinking about the right things, however I'm still confused by the original vector definition as an equivalence class and reflected that in my post.  I tried defining it in the original post, but the definitions do not seem to fit unless arithmetic operations are defined for the class.

Comment: I've given the definition of vector addition for equivalence classes already. Scalar multiplication could be defined on bound vectors ($\lambda \overrightarrow{PQ}$ could be the vector $\overrightarrow{PQ'}$ where $Q = P + \lambda(Q-P)$, and then this extends to equivalence classes by applying it to every element of the equivalence class at once.

Comment: I understand the equivalence class now.  Regarding the Wiki definitions $\vec E = \{\vec{PQ} : P \in E \land Q \in E\}$.  If they are only using free vectors where $\vec{PQ} = Q - P$, why not just assume the origin $P = \vec{0}$ such that $\vec E = \{\vec{v} : \vec{v} \in E\}$?

Comment: @Nick Because for affine subspaces, the origin is not necessarily an element of $E$. For example, if we are in $\mathbb R^2$ and $E$ is the set $\{(x,y): x=1\}$, then the Wiki definition correctly says that $\vec E$ is the set of all vectors of the form $(0,y)$. Your proposed definition doesn't give a vector space.

Comment: You mention that two bound vectors A, B can only be added if A's terminal point is B's initial point and that in a vector space we should be able to add any two vectors.  It appears that any two free vectors which are defined as the equivalence relation can be added (see $+_v$ in my post).  The equivalence relation contains all vectors of the same direction and length, of which there will be one B with initial point the same as A's terminal point.  To convert the equivalence relation definition of a free vector to a single free I provide that in the above post.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.